# How to pass file to php using file picker.io

Tags: php, file-upload, filepicker.io

I would be very happy to find out how to pass a single mp3 file to the php by post method using file picker.io

Comment: I passed JSON array containing URLs from Javascript to php and downloaded files by those URLs in php. Wanna me to describe it in more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you use datepicker.io the selected files are automatically stored in the datepicker server. Then, you can read the file from the public url (the API give the public url in the response) and store it (with CURL for example?)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I will try to find out, however still not very clear how I do it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible:

```
>>> curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@filename.txt https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=MY_API_KEY
{"url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WmFxB2aSe20SGT2kzSsr", "size": 234, "type": "text/plain", "filename": "tester.txt", "key": "1ilWxmaRRqhMd2vSbSyB_tester.txt"}
```

or

```
>>> curl -X POST -d url="https://www.filepicker.io/static/img/watermark.png" https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=MY_API_KEY
{"url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/N49i6hPRBeropWnCWOLw", "size": 8331, "type": "image/png", "filename": "watermark.png", "key": "a1RyBxiglW92bS2SRmqM_watermark.png"}
```

Full documentation at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-store

Comment: In my answer I was thinking in PHP-CURL, but yes, this example has the same functionality but in the console.